# Does there exists any non singular $2\times 2$ integer matrices $A,B,C$ satisfying $A^4+B^4=C^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Does there exists any non singular $2\times 2$ integer matrices $A,B,C$ satisfying $A^4+B^4=C^2$?

There are many singular matrices are there satisfying this condition. But non singular matrices, I have unable to find. Or may be there is non nonsigular matrices there satisfying this condition.

Comment: $A_{11} = 1$ and zero otherwise. $B_{22} = 1$ and zero otherwise and $C = I$.

Comment: @Gregory: $A$ and $B$ are both singular in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  Let $(a,b,c)$ be a Pythagorean triple.  Then
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
&a\\
1\end{pmatrix}^4+\begin{pmatrix}&b\\1\end{pmatrix}^4=(cI)^2
$$